# Shell command date

Tags: shell, date, unix, sh

I want to print date in the mm-dd-yy format in shell script. From shell terminal I can get it using the following command:

```
date +"%d-%m-%y"
```

But I want it in the shell script and in a variable which could then be appended to a file name. I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
mydate=`"date +\"%m-%d-%Y\""'
echo "$mydate"
```

But it is giving an error `date +"%d-%m-%y" is not found.` 
Can anybody point out what mistake am I making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need quotes

```
mydate=`date +%m-%d-%Y`
```

will work.

Comment: +1 In general, `$(date +%m-%d-%Y)` is recommended over backquotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
mydate=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y")
```

See this is a way to store a command in a variable: `var=$(command)`. To use `date`, you define the format like `date "+%format%place%holders"`, with `+` inside the double quotes.

```
$ mydate=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y")
$ echo $mydate
09-29-2014
```

Note it is preferred to use `$()` over ``, because it allows nesting multiple commands.

Comment: @CrazyC oh I see what happened. I have `$` in the beginning of the line to indicate the shell prompt. The command I meant you to use is just `mydate=$(date)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have advice about how to do it properly. The reason for the error is the first level of inner double quotes makes the entire command with arguments into a single word:

```
mydate=`"date +\"%m-%d-%Y\""'
```

You are trying to execute a command named:

> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

and clearly no such command exists.

Comment: Good explanation and visual art!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
mydate=`date +\"%m-%d-%Y\"`
mydate1=`date +%m-%d-%Y`
echo "$mydate"
echo "$mydate1"
```

Both approaches will work. But the first one will have the date value surrounded by double quotes, something like "09-29-2014".